# Is "Colorado" also a fish?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The movie [No Reservations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Reservations_(film)) has a fish market scene:

> Woman: Good. What you got?
>
> Fishmonger: I got fresh bluefin. Just came in like five minutes ago. I got baby mullets over there.
>
> Woman: What's behind you there?
>
> Fishmonger: **Colorados**.
>
> Woman: Yeah, I'm gonna take some of those.

I am not sure if it refers to the state fish. I think it's doubtful. What is he talking about here? At Tᴚoɯɐuo's suggestion, I have added an [audio clip](https://clyp.it/qntbk1rd) to enrich the context (via Clyp, an audio sharing site).

Comment: Is he speaking with an American accent? Is he hispanic?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo He has a generic American accent. Honestly, if he had an accent that indicates foreign/immigrant background, I'd have mentioned it in the original post. I have just uploaded an audio clip of the conversation to add to the context. So any chance you would reconsider the downvote...?

Comment: We have no idea whether you could detect the difference between a native speaker of English and someone with a slight hispanic accent, so I asked if you knew anything more about the speaker. But I've upvoted now that you've added the sound clip.

Comment: State fishes are not referred to by the name of their state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It is a type of snapper found in the Pacific.  Colorado means "coloured" or "red" in Spanish, and this is a red fish. This word doesn't seem to be in the dictionaries, it is probably local to the coastal communities that fish those waters.

Example, on [fishbase](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/Lutjanus-colorado.html)

(the state fish of Colorado is the Greenback cutthroat trout)

Comment: +1. **pargo colorado** http://spanishdict.com/translate/el%20pargo%20colorado